# Django: How to provide context into a FormView get() method (also using request param)

Tags: python, django, django-views

I'm trying to provide some additional context into the get() method in my FormView. I need get() because I need to run some logic first, check for a potential redirect. I also need access to the request object (because I need to check session data). Can't figure out how to do it. Simplified code below..

**Attempt 1:**

```
class LoginView(FormView):
   template_name = 'members/login.html'
   form_class = LoginForm

   def get(self, request):
      # check if to redirect
      if self.request.session.get('user'):
         return redirect('/dashboard/')

      # render page with extra context
      else:
         context = super(LoginView, self).get(request)
         context['message'] = self.request.session['message']
         return context
```

No errors, but context does not come through in the template.

**Attempt 2:**

```
class LoginView(FormView):
   template_name = 'members/login.html'
   form_class = LoginForm

   def get_context_data(self, request, **kwargs):
      # check if to redirect
      if self.request.session.get('user'):
         return redirect('/dashboard/')

      # render page with extra context
      else:
         context = super(LoginView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
         context['message'] = self.request.session['message']
         return context
```

Getting `TypeError: get_context_data() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)`

*P.S. This work relates to a workaround Django's buggy messages middleware which seems to be working locally flawlessly but on live (Heroku) is not 100% reliable, renders on some pages only. Ugh, frustration setting in...*

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ditch the `request` argument to [the `get_context_data` method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/class-based-views/mixins-simple/#django.views.generic.base.ContextMixin.get_context_data). You should also use the [dispatch](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/class-based-views/base/#django.views.generic.base.View.dispatch) method to check if the user is logged in.

```
class LoginView(FormView):
    template_name = 'members/login.html'
    form_class = LoginForm

    def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
        """Use this to check for 'user'."""
        if request.session.get('user'):
            return redirect('/dashboard/')
        return super(LoginView, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        """Use this to add extra context."""
        context = super(LoginView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['message'] = self.request.session['message']
        return context
```

Comment: Thank you, that did it. Hmm, I thought I always have to pass in the request object, otherwise it wouldn't have access to it. Just as I thought I had a handle on Django's class-based views..

Comment: or use the [LoginRequiredMixin](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/auth/default/#the-loginrequiredmixin-mixin)